# EmailClient for Business Office to manage send or receive emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-client

We have a customer ( a business office ) which wants to manage their employees business emails.
1- a copy of all emails which send from business email account, send to another email address as BCC ( employees can't disable this option )
2- a copy of all received email address send to another email address automatically.
3- all employees have a folder in third party email (which set as BCC) and emails that send to it, move to a specific folder.

I can manage option 2 and 3 by outlook setting and mail server settings,but is it possible to set first option in outlook? or anyone knows another email clients which can do these options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Visual Basic plugin to tell Outlook to automatically BCC a recipient address.

A detailed tutorial can be found [here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/).

A good thing about this plugin is that it will appear as though the BCC field is empty, which means staff will not know or be able to change the email address in the BCC field.

Answer (score 1):

Well, although you immediately accepted the first response, I'll just throw another idea out there: don't do it client side.

There are a lot of products that do all this stuff. Check out Microsoft's Forefront, McAfee's mxLogic (or whatever they call it these days) or Postini as a couple of the common solutions. Do it all server side.

You do this stuff client side and where are you when the employees start processing their e-mail from their own phones/tables/web interfaces?